# EC2 runs out of storage, which logs etc. can be deleted?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, storage

I am having a problem with an EC2 which uses nearly all of the 8GB of storage. I regularly delete log files from the server and files which get created by cronjobs in the users folder (can I turn this off?), but in the past there is always less space after deleting all the files. So somewhere else the EC2 creates files, but I don't know where.

Does anybody know where I can look for unused files automatically created by the Amazon Linux AMI or apache?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in `/var/log`, and for Apache they will likely be in `/var/log/httpd`. I also suggest that you look into [logrotate](http://iain.cx/src/logrotate/).

Comment: Hi thanks, that are actually the folders which i am constantly cleaning, however still less and less space over time..

Comment: You can use the `du` command to help find where you have large amounts of storage. Look in `/var` first, running `du -s` on each directory. You might also consider mounting another EBS volume somewhere on your server, such as `/var`, to help offload this storage to a larger drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all log files from your ec2 Ubuntu instance using this command

`sudo rm -rf /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/`